# Create model out of a sharepoint list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

in my new project i have to intergrate mvc into sharepoint. Ie in an mvc project we are using sharepoint as a data layer. so we need to get sharepoint list as a model in mvc.

Is there any open source tool which create model out of a sharepoint list??

Can any one help me with this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [SPMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538255%28v=office.14%29.aspx), this tool + LINQ to SharePoint make your life easier.

SPMetal is a command-line tool and it generates entity classes for your project, so then you're able to access to the SharePoint lists and libraries using LINQ to SharePoint. You'll be able to get, add, delete and change list items.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168714/Using-SPMetal) you have a cool example.

Enjoy!